# android/Windows Application viber(chat examples)

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, sql

Does anybody have an example or a tutorial for Android/Windows Application like viber? I want to understand how viber works and how it is programmed and how it works with different application.

I want to see an example that uses a message-chat-system that can work with different application.
I tested different way to do this but I faced with problems, so I think that I did not choose good way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of applications are developed using [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) protocol and here is the sample for developing the server app in Google App Engine Using Java

[Google App Engine and XMPP in Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/)

http://xmppjingle.blogspot.in/2009/11/google-app-engine-xmpp-services-example.html

http://googleappengine.blogspot.in/2009/10/interactive-xmpp-demos.html

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.in/2013/07/multi-channel-chat-with-twilio-and.html